# Gradle settings groovy file to kts file

Tags: gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have this as `settings.gradle`

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.net.vivin:gradle-semantic-build-versioning:4.0.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'net.vivin.gradle-semantic-build-versioning'
```

I need to convert it to a `settings.gradle.kts` kotlin DSL file. I tried:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("gradle.plugin.net.vivin:gradle-semantic-build-versioning:4.0.0")
    }
}

apply ("gradle.plugin.net.vivin.gradle-semantic-build-versioning")
```

This gives the error:

> Cannot apply plugin of class 'org.gradle.api.Plugin' to
>   'net.vivin.gradle-semantic-build-versioning' (class: java.lang.String)
>   as it does not implement PluginAware

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
plugins.apply("net.vivin.gradle-semantic-build-versioning")
```